# How to fetch employer detail of facebook logged In user

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook SDK 3.5 for integrating facebook login and fetching details of logged In user via android application. Please have a look over my code where i could achieve to fetch various info of logged In user.

```
Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
        if (user != null) {
            String firstName = user.getFirstName();
            String lastName = user.getLastName();
            String id = user.getId();
            String email = user.getProperty("email").toString();


            Log.e("facebookid", id);
            Log.e("firstName", firstName);
            Log.e("lastName", lastName);
            Log.e("email", email);


            String total = id + "," + firstName + "," + lastName +","+email;
            welcome.setText(total);
            System.out.println("##facebookid"+ id);
            System.out.println("##firstName"+ firstName);
            System.out.println("##lastName"+ lastName);
            System.out.println("##email"+ email);
        }
    }
});
```

But i didn't find any clue about the Employer Details of logged In user. How can i achieve this information. Is that possible or no. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This functionality appears to be provided at user endpoint using additional parameters concordant with your search.

For example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=work
```

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

- `work`: A list of the user's work history

  - Permission tokens: `user_work_history` or `friends_work_history`
  - Returns: array of objects containing employer, location, position, start_date and end_date fields

You can reasonably find the user's current employer by inspecting the `start_date` and `end_date` respectively. For a different user than the current user, replace `me` with the desired `PROFILE_ID`.

do like this

```
session.openForRead(new Session.OpenRequest(activity)
                    .setCallback(statusCallback)
                    .setPermissions(
                            Arrays.asList("user_work_history,email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,user_about_me,user_relationships,friends_about_me,friends_likes,friends_photos")));
```

after you can do this in your userinfo function

```
user.getProperty("work").toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. What should i use for fetching employer details among these Arrays.asList("email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown,user_about_me,user_relationships,friends_about_me,friends_likes,friends_photos")

Comment: do you want facebook employer list?

Comment: I added user_work_history in Permissions but it's nothing to fetch just null.  String employer = user.getProperty("user_work_history").toString();

Comment: not like that do as my edit answer see that how i request permission "work".

Comment: sorry @SureshSharma i mistcally swaped paramiter now it will work see edit answer